# LINQ to SQL inserting large object from .NET

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

What is the fastest way to get a list object with a count of 100,000 records into SQL using LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

```
MyContext.Items.InsertAllOnSubmit( 
    from i in list
    select new Item
    {
       //map properties
    });
```

Ps. Haven't tried inserting that much data though

Comment: That will be very slow.  LINQ-to-SQL will generate single insert statements for each record.

Answer (score 3):

For mass data, the *fastest* way is to use something like [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to push the data (via a crafted `IDataReader`) into a staging table (same layout, but no indexes/etc) - and then use [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) to execute a stored procedure to push the data from the staging table into the real table. But note that LINQ-to-SQL isn't involved here (unless you use it to invoke the stored procedure).

You could try just using regular LINQ-to-SQL `InsertOnSubmit` - assess how big a problem the volume of data is before you try to optimise it; it might be "fast enough" even though sub-optimal.

You can create an `IDataReader` fairly easily; I often use the csv on from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx). To create one from a list, you could borrow `SimpleDataReader` from [here](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/msg/b1d70b504cdee2ad) and override `DoRead`.

Comment: Trying to work on this issue myself, as InsertOnSubmit for my 160,000 records has taken all day so far.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ2SQL does not support batch inserts. Look at running your own SQL, or use another framework that does support it (I recall the Entity Framework does, but I cant be sure).

Comment: Somebody have a problem with my answer? Speak up, I cant hear you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to specify exactly where is the source of your 100,000 records coming from.

If you are retrieving the records from a non-database source, the fastest way I know to insert the records is by using the InsertAllOnSubmit method. Of course, this means 100,000 insert statements in a transaction, but without further details there isn't much choice in the matter.

If you are retrieving the records from a database, the performance will be better if you call a stored procedure instead. For example, in your stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT * FROM TableB
```

Then, you call the stored procedure with LINQ.

Comment: Even for non-database, you can use bulk transfer via SqlBulkCopy; there are lots of ways of creating an IDataReader, not just from a db.